# imagemagick convert dng - changes date modified

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert, datemodified, dng

Edit 26/04/2016 : This is a bug that has been fixed in ImageMagick-6.9.3-5 and 7.0.0-0

.

Converting DNG files, when I run

```
convert "my_img.dng" "my_img_converted.jpg"
```

Imagemagick changes the date modified of the original `my_img.dng` to the time when conversion happened.

.

Do you know how to avoid that and keep the original file intact?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that is a bug! A workaround is as follows:

```
convert dng:- result.jpg < original.dng
```

Or, equivalently if you prefer reading left-to-right and don't mind superfluous processes:

```
cat original.dng | convert dng:- result.jpg
```

Comment: @GlennRanders-Pehrson I tried running `ufraw` myself outside of ImageMagick and that didn't change the date on the DNG, so I wasn't sure who was to blame. Do you have an account on IM forum - I don't myself - if so, maybe you would care to bring it to their attention. Or maybe I should join up...

Comment: I do, but thought I'd investigate first. We'd be glad to have you on the IM forums; go to http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server to join or to lurk as a guest.

Comment: Verified the bahavior described by OP and by @MarkSetchell: "convert in.dng out.png" changes the timestamp of "in.dng".  But "ufraw-batch  --silent --create-id=also --out-type=png --out-depth=16  --output=out.png in.dng", which is the "delegate" command used by ImageMagick, does not.  This test with ImageMagick-7.0.0, current version, and ufraw-batch version 0.22.

Comment: Bug reported upstream: http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=29141

Comment: This bug has been fixed in ImageMagick-6.9.3-5 and 7.0.0-0

Comment: Thank you, @GlennRanders-Pehrson for getting this sorted out.

Comment: @GlennRanders-Pehrson and Mark Setchell - Thanks for reporting and sorting this out guys. This has also been happening with cr2's and nef file formats. Do you know if it has been fixed for these too?

Comment: @Voy I haven't tested NEF or CR2, but since they both are handled with the DNG+ufraw-batch codec in ImageMagick, I expect that those are also fixed.

Comment: @GlennRanders-Pehrson Right, I thought so too. I'll try to get back once I test that fix on nef and cr2's. Once again, thanks for help!

Comment: @GlennRanders-Pehrson I can confirm it's been fixed for CR2 and NEF files too. Used version 6.9.3-8 Q16 x64. Regards :)